# Where does "Blonde" diverge from the book?

Tags: blonde

The 2022 film *Blonde*, which is loosely based on the life story of Marilyn Monroe, has attracted some mixed reactions, with some people indicating that it contains a number of events that never occurred or are not known to have occurred in Monroe's life, as detailed in [this article](https://theweek.com/movies/1017051/blonde?utm_campaign=afternoon_newsletter_20220929&utm_source=afternoon_newsletter&utm_medium=email&refid=07AF1DC0B0886DDCC7AF64EEF568A2D9) (warning: fairly graphic descriptions of violence).

However, the film is based on a [2000 novel by Joyce Carol Oates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blonde_%28novel%29?wprov=sfla1) As such, to what extent does the film follow the book, particularly with regard to elements where the film diverges from Monroe's life? Specifically, which plot points were invented for the film, and which were invented by Oates?